# Multiselect combobox with typeahead feature

Tags: extjs, combobox

Is there a way we can enable typeAhead feature for Mutiselect Combobox ? I don't need it in a tagfield.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, but you can always override the combobox and re-implement the [`onTypeAhead`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/src/ComboBox.js.html#line1015) function.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for your reply. I am trying to override the combobox and in the initcomponent of override I have commented the below code:if (me.typeAhead && me.multiSelect) {
   //Ext.raise('typeAhead and multiSelect are mutually exclusive options -- please remove one of them.');
  }                                                                                                     
However at last me.callParent(); is being called and it calls the original extjs combo and I get the following error
"typeAhead and multiSelect are mutually exclusive options -- please remove one of them"

Comment: And If I comment me.callParent() then I get another error plugin.init is not a function.Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: How about `me.typeAhead = false; me.callParent(); me.typeAhead=true`?